# xlwings VBA No Moudle Found

Tags: python, xlwings

I am currently using xlwings for writing script to my Excel
The code can work while under this code

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    xw.Book('option_excel.xlsm').set_mock_caller()
    output1()
```

But it does not work well in the excel, when I press the VBA button.
There is a sub-module called by the output1 function

[image: Error occurs in excel]

Comment: Please don't screenshot your code.

Answer (score 0):

From the limited amount of information in your Stack trace, it appears that you have capitalized `Option` in `Option_analysis` when it should be the name of the module you wrote, `option_analysis`. Python is case-sensitive.

Comment: I do have 2 python package functions cal_table and main under the Option_analysis package. What I am doing is add a connection between the main and cal_table. It works well in python but seem not working while I using the xlwings VBA button.  
from Option_analysis.function.cal_table import core_table

Comment: yes. that one. should not start with a capital O, if your stack trace doesn't lie